# Converting a string to two strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, strings

I have the following code that converts a string that looks like:

> aaa-bbb|ccc-ddd|eee-fff

to two strings that look like:

> aaa|ccc|eee`and`bbb|ddd|fff

The code works fine, but I am wondering if I probably missed some string/array functions that can makes the job in fewer operations / or with faster runtime.

```
var id = "HEL-CAS|MAD-STO|XXX-YYY"
var splittedId = id.split('|');
var from = "",
  to = "";
$(splittedId).each(function(a, b) {
  from = from + b.split("-")[0] + "|";
  to = to + b.split("-")[1] + "|";
});
from = from.substring(0, from.length - 1);
to = to.substring(0, to.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use some ES6 functions and have something like:

```
var s = 'HEL-CAS|MAD-STO|XXX-YYY';
var s1 = [];
var s2 = []

for (var v of s.split('|').map(str => str.split('-'))) {
  s1.push(v[0])
  s2.push(v[1])
}

s1.join('|')
s2.join('|')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `from` and `to` to array and use `array.join()`. This might help you if you wish to process certain values in this list later.

```js
var str = "HEL-CAS|MAD-STO|XXX-YYY"
var from = [], to = [];
str.split('|').forEach(function(item){
  var _tmp = item.split("-");
  from.push(_tmp[0]);
  to.push(_tmp[1]);
});

console.log(from.join("|"), to.join("|"));
```

Comment: You probably meant `from.join("|")` .. but still I would love to have some profiler information between the two versions (mine and yours)

Comment: @najibla Inspired by your question, I actually widened its requirement so rather than an answer I posted it as a new question. You can look at it [here] (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119722/reformatting-a-structured-string-like-a-b-ca-b-c-into-a-ab-bc-c).